# How to embed a maven dependency with bnd-maven-plugin

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi, bnd, bndtools, maven-bundle-plugin

I am moving from maven-bundle-plugin which provided the "convenient" configuration using Embed-Dependency, but it appears i need to specify my Embed Dependency "manually" in bnd format when using the `bnd-maven-plugin`. I added the same bundle headers from my old package, but it doesn't seem to be including the actual dependency's jar file. Does someone have a quick/concise how-to do this?

Comment: Why are you switching to bnd-maven-plugin if the maven-bundle-plugin already supports your use-case?

Comment: Well, maven-bundle-plugin is getting out of date with bndlib. bnd-maven-plugin comes from the Bnd maintainers.

Answer (score 5):

bnd has an instruction `-includeresource` defined here https://bnd.bndtools.org/instructions/includeresource.html:

Here's an example:

```
-includeresource: lib/somelib.jar=somelib-[\w.]*.jar;lib:=true
```

This should have visibility into all the dependencies in the classpath used to build the artifact and matches on the file name of the associated files.

[Update with BJ's comment]
The `lib:=true` will automatically add the jar to the bundle's Bundle-ClassPath header in a *merge safe way* (i.e. by making sure it plays nice with existing content or non-existent value).

Comment: The `lib:=true` will automatically add the jar to the bundle's `Bundle-ClassPath` header.

Comment: Could you please update your answer to also explain how to include transitive dependencies ?

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to specify transitive inclusion natively in bnd.